# Long documents on R Sweave include files

Tags: r, latex

I'm writing a book in R Sweave, as long as the document is becoming larger I use the `\include` LaTeX command to include files. When I PDF-Compile the main file the files with R chunks are not included. What extension they must have .tex or .Rnw?

Comment: I think .tex but I could be wrong. You might have better luck on the [TeX SE site](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can also take a look at how [knitr handles child documents](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/). It offers somewhat more flexible interface for these kinds of complex projects compared to Sweave.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Sweave User Manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf), p. 7

> Latex files can include others via \input{} commands.  These can
>   also be used in Sweave files, but the included files will be included by
>   Latex and are not processed by Sweave. The equivalent if you want
>   the included files to be processed is the \SweaveInput{} command.
>   Included files should use the same Sweave syntax (see below) and
>   encoding as the main file.

Comment: Hi,     I appreciate your help. \SweaveInput do the magic! Carlos